# Initializing a Flask WTFForm class variable to be used in SelectField

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask-wtforms

I am trying to read a list from a db , populate a variable and use this variable in a list.

I am using Flask WTF, python 2.7

The way the application is build:

The form.py

```
class NewStatusForm(Form):
  SOURCE=[]
  source_id = SelectField('Source Code', [DataRequired()],
        choices = OrderedDict(SOURCE),prepend_blank = False)

  def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    # Call Flask-SQLAlchemy's constructor.
    super(NewStatusForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        if key=='sources':
            SOURCE=value
```

I want the variable SOURCE to hold the list from a db

views.py looks like:

```
@status_blueprint.route('/status/new', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def status_new()

form = 
NewStatusForm(obj=status, sources=global_list_of_sources)
```

the global_list_of_sources contains the list from db

the form.html is quite simple

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ source_id.label }} {{ source_id }}
<input type="submit" value="Select">
```

How can I initialize SOURCE to sources in order to get the list?
Right now I always get SOURCE empty = [] and no list with source_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around  :

in the views.py

```
 form = NewStatusForm(obj = status)


 form.source_id.choices=OrderedDict(global_list_of_sources),prepend_blank = False)
```

and in the forms.py:

```
source_id = SelectField('Source Code', [DataRequired()],choices = [])
```